# Batching of Dataset Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to create batches of rows of `Dataset` in Spark.
For maintaining the number of records sent to service I want to batch the items so that i can maintain the rate at which the data will be sent.
For,

```
case class Person(name:String, address: String)
case class PersonBatch(personBatch: List[Person])
```

For a given `Dataset[Person]` I want to create `Dataset[PersonBatch]`

For example if input `Dataset[Person]` has 100 records the output `Dataset` should be like `Dataset[PersonBatch]` where every `PersonBatch`should be list of `n` records (Person).

I have tried this but it din't work.

```
object DataBatcher extends Logger {

  var batchList: ListBuffer[PersonBatch] = ListBuffer[PersonBatch]()
  var batchSize: Long = 500  //default batch size

  def addToBatchList(batch: PersonBatch): Unit = {
    batchList += batch
  }

  def clearBatchList(): Unit = {
    batchList.clear()
  }

  def createBatches(ds: Dataset[Person]): Dataset[PersonBatch] = {

    val dsCount = ds.count()
    logger.info(s"Count of dataset passed for creating batches : ${dsCount}")
    val batchElement = ListBuffer[Person]()
    val batch = PersonBatch(batchElement)
    ds.foreach(x => {
      batch.personBatch += x
      if(batch.personBatch.length == batchSize) {
        addToBatchList(batch)
        batch.requestBatch.clear()
      }
    })
    if(batch.personBatch.length > 0) {
      addToBatchList(batch)
      batch.personBatch.clear()
    }
    sparkSession.createDataset(batchList)
  }  
}
```

I want to run this job on Hadoop cluster.
Can some help me with this ?

Answer (score 1):

rdd.iterator has grouped function may be useful for you.

for example :

> iter.grouped(batchSize)

Sample code snippet which does batch insert with iter.grouped(batchsize) here its 1000 and Im trying to insert in to database

```
   df.repartition(numofpartitionsyouwant) // numPartitions ~ number of simultaneous DB connections you can planning to give...
def insertToTable(sqlDatabaseConnectionString: String,
                  sqlTableName: String): Unit = {

  val tableHeader: String = dataFrame.columns.mkString(",")
  dataFrame.foreachPartition { partition =>
    //NOTE : EACH PARTITION ONE CONNECTION (more better way is to use connection pools)
    val sqlExecutorConnection: Connection =
      DriverManager.getConnection(sqlDatabaseConnectionString)
    //Batch size of 1000 is used since some databases cant use batch size more than 1000 for ex : Azure sql
    partition.grouped(1000).foreach { group =>
      val insertString: scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder =
        new scala.collection.mutable.StringBuilder()

      group.foreach { record =>
        insertString.append("('" + record.mkString(",") + "'),")
      }

      sqlExecutorConnection
        .createStatement()
        .executeUpdate(f"INSERT INTO [$sqlTableName] ($tableHeader) VALUES "
          + insertString.stripSuffix(","))
    }

    sqlExecutorConnection.close() // close the connection so that connections wont exhaust.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val tableHeader: String = dataFrame.columns.mkString(",")
dataFrame.foreachPartition((it: Iterator[Row]) => {
      println("partition index: " )
      val url = "jdbc:...+ "user=;password=;"
      val conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url)
      conn.setAutoCommit(true)
      val stmt = conn.createStatement()
      val batchSize = 10
      var i =0
      while (it.hasNext) {
        val row = it.next
        import java.sql.SQLException
        import java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException
        try {
          stmt.addBatch(" UPDATE TABLE SET STATUS = 0 , " +
            " DATE ='" + new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()) +"'" +
            " where id = " + row.getAs("IDNUM")  )
          i += 1
          if (  i  % batchSize == 0 ) {
            stmt.executeBatch
            conn.commit
          }
        } catch {
          case e: SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException =>
          case e: SQLException =>
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        finally {
             stmt.executeBatch
             conn.commit
        }

      }
      import java.util
      val ret = stmt.executeBatch
      System.out.println("Ret val: " + util.Arrays.toString(ret))
      System.out.println("Update count: " + stmt.getUpdateCount)
      conn.commit
      stmt.close
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have a same problem,
I wanted to read data from Snowflake in batches of 1000 rows and writes it to a Delta table.

I searched everywhere but received nothing, I have got a solution using the offset value, hope this helps you.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import util.control.Breaks._

val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .appName("SnowflakeToDB")
  .getOrCreate()

val sfOptions = Map(
  "sfUrl" -> "{SNOWFLAKE_URL}",
  "sfUser" -> "{SNOWFLAKE_USER_NAME}",
  "sfPassword" -> "{SNOWFLAKE_PASSWORD}",
  "sfDatabase" -> "CITY_BIKE",
  "sfSchema" -> "PUBLIC",
  "sfWarehouse" -> "COMPUTE_WH"
)

var offset = 0
val limit = 1000

while (true) {

  // Read data from Snowflake
  val df = spark.read
    .format("net.snowflake.spark.snowflake")
    .options(sfOptions)
    .option("query", s"select * from trips order by BIKEID limit $limit offset $offset")
    .load()

  if (df.isEmpty) {
    println("No more data to read")
    break
  }

  // Write data to the Database
  df.write.format("delta").mode("append").saveAsTable("{DELTA_TABLE_NAME}")

  offset += limit
}
```